# How do I revert to having sudo ask for a password again?

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords, sudo

I accidentally made a mistake and made my `sudo` commands passwordless on my Mac. How can I get it back to default?

Answer (score 4):

From `man sudoers`:

> NOPASSWD and PASSWD
>
> By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself
>   before running a command.  This behavior can be modified via the
>   NOPASSWD tag.

You either added the `NOPASSWD` tag or enabled an entry with a `NOPASSWD` tag.

In any case, edit `/etc/sudoers` with command `visudo` (which needs sudo) and remove or comment out the entry.

For example, with these entries I can run any command without being asked for a password:

```
jaume   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%localaccounts  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

`%localaccounts` means group localaccounts, of which I'm a member:

```
$ id
uid=501(jaume) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts)
```

On the other hand, if the entry lacks `NOPASSWD` I must authenticate:

```
jaume   ALL=(ALL) ALL
%staff  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

You can have both behaviors with an entry like this:

```
jaume   ALL=(ALL) ALL,NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/softwareupdate
```

Here I need to authenticate for any command except for `softwareupdate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the **sudoers** file to make sudo require a password again.  You need to edit this file using the **sudo visudo** command in a terminal session and removing the line:

> %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

which is probably near the end of the file.  Then save (write) the file and quit.  The **visudo** command verifies the new file and "installs" it.  You may need to restart or at least logoff and on to have this take place.

Note that the **visudo** command puts you in the **vi** editor so you need to know a little about using **vi** to make the changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I was unable to locate `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL` when I edited the file. The only one I saw that was kind of the same was `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: @Anonymous: Open Terminal and run `id` as shown above in my answer. If `wheel` is one of the groups shown that's the entry to comment out.

Comment: t@Anonymous: Sorry that my answer wasn't on the mark.  If you look at the **sudoers** file description (**man sudoers**) you'll see more info about it than you'll ever want to see (which is my best excuse). As jaume added in his comment, f the %wheel line is the only one with NOPASSWD then that should be removed or better commented out(i upvoted his answer); if there are other lines with the NOPASSWD you might want to get more advice as to which is causing this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look in /etc/sudoers for 'NOPASSWD:' and remove it. If you're game, try running this in a terminal window:
"sed -i 's/ NOPASSWD://g'"
You can test it without the -i switch first if you want.

Comment: It says _Permission Denied_

Comment: Sorry, since it is a system file you need to run the command as root or use sudo: `sudo sed -i 's/ NOPASSWD://g`

Answer (score 0):

Does your account have root/sudoer privs?

If so, try:

`sudo -i`

And then

`passwd`

That puts you into super user mode based on your account, and then resets the root password (which may do what you need since you said the visudo file sounds about right.).