# How do I disable su on Macbook Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, su

I'm taking my macbook into the shop for service. I want to create an account that has no access to anything but its own user directory. In Yosemite, when I create a new account without administrator privileges I can still su and sudo without being asked for a password. Everything I read says I should have to enable the root account for this to occur. I have specifically disabled root. How do I prevent my "applestore" account from accessing my /users/myadminaccount directory? ...from terminal.

In summary, when I enter 'su' at the command prompt I am immediately granted root access. There is no request for a password. How do I disable su completely?

Edit: removed sudo from the discussion. How do I prevent su from running without asking for a password? root account is now enabled with a password.

Comment: passwd http://ss64.com/osx/passwd.html

Comment: `su` and `sudo` are different programs. su should always ask for a password (assuming you have a root password set. If not set one using `open /System/Library/CoreServices/Directory\ Utility.app`)

Comment: As for `sudo`: See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html and http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html#x5355444f4552532046494c4520464f524d4154 and http://superuser.com/questions/509990/how-do-i-revert-to-having-sudo-ask-for-a-password-again

Comment: This is an exercise in futility. All I would need to do is start your macbook in target disk mode and your files are mine.

Comment: @fd0 even if my drive is encrypted?

Comment: True. A safe way would be to leave the OP's harddisk at home. Which I think is normal if you need to sent in a laptop for repair. But in this case 'for service' is rather vague and can mean a lot of things.

Comment: I'm going to the genius bar to get them to put in a new battery. I'm just going to hand them my laptop. They're going to need to go through their normal list of stupid questions which will include looking at battery cycles, etc, which will require a bootable hard drive.

Comment: @Hennes Whether root is enabled with a passwd or not, the non admin user can still run su without being asked for a password (and without requiring sudo).

Comment: Weird. I that case my regular BSD knowledge does not match with OS X (and no Mac here to test on, so best I could offer is general unix/BSD knowledge).